# OR and AND combination fail MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I tried to figure out which mysql code to use. I tried the following script which contains all search features I need:

```
SELECT * FROM `zk_posts` WHERE `form_id` IN (3,6) 
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(published, '%Y') = 2013 
AND `message` LIKE '%search%' 
OR `description` LIKE '%search%' 
OR `name` LIKE '%search%';
```

At first I want to only show posts where form_id is 3 or 6 and the published year is 2013. At the same time I want to search inside my text columns, if there is any match inside one of these three, but by using OR in combination with AND it doesn't work the way I want. If I run this mysql it returns posts which for example don't match with the form_id.

Can anyone tell me how he or she would solve this.

Comment: Use parentheses when you are combining multiple conditions in the `where` clause.  That will fix your problem.

Comment: Use some `()` to group clauses.

Comment: It sounds very good! Although I'm not very familiar to that, but I'm going to do a bit of research! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
SELECT * FROM `zk_posts` WHERE `form_id` IN (3,6) 
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(published, '%Y') = 2013 
AND (`message` LIKE '%search%' 
OR `description` LIKE '%search%' 
OR `name` LIKE '%search%');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The comments above already told me to make group classes but you already did the work :D! Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You need brackets to enforce the order in which mysql evaluates those conditions. Probably something like this:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE (`form_id` in (3,6))
    AND (FROM_UNIXTIME(published, '%Y') = 2013)
    AND (
       message LIKE '%search%'
       OR description LIKE '%search%'
       OR name LIKE '%searc%'
    )
```

as written, your query is treated like

```
... WHERE (everything else)
    OR (message LIKE ...)
    OR (description LIKE ...)
    OR (name LIKE ...)
```

which would evaluate to TRUE if the search terms are in any of those three fields, regardless of the rest of the conditions.

Comment: Yeah I already thought it would be treated like that. I only didn't knew how to make sure that didn't happen anymore. I'm really thankfull for all your work. I posted this question and I almost immediatly got the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? (please notice **parentheses** around `OR` conditions)

```
 SELECT * FROM `zk_posts` 
WHERE `form_id` IN (3,6) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(published, '%Y') = 2013 AND 
(`message` LIKE '%search%' OR `description` LIKE '%search%' OR `name` LIKE '%search%');
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Are you guys constantly solving other peoples problems?! Your great!